# UIActivityViewController with custom UI

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

[UIActivityViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aLh5.png)

As shown in above the image , I want custom image and a text in marked places when I share data using UIActivityViewController from my app.

```
NSString *text = @"Custom Title";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [shareLink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
UIImage *appIconImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"IconImage.png"];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:appIconImage,text ,url, nil];
UIActivityViewController *controller =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc]
 initWithActivityItems:array
 applicationActivities:nil];

[controller setValue:@"Custom title" forKey:@"subject"];

controller.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                     UIActivityTypePrint,
                                     UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                     UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                     UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                     UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                     UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
```

Comment: please share your code where you are building UIActivityViewController

Comment: @jawadAli code added.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the image urls to UIActivityViewController not the UIImage objects.

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:appIconImageURL,text ,url, nil];
```

Hope it helps!